# Is there such mysql syntax to end/limit mysql query?

Tags: mysql, validation, filter

Is there any mysql syntax to stop the query from being append by user input? If the query is

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `username`
    WHERE `type` = 'client'
    END / LIMIT / whatever syntax here;
```

the query should stop at `'client'` so if user try to add his own query by adding `OR` such as this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM `username`
    WHERE `type` = 'client'
    OR 1 = 1;
```

it will not work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are using PHP and that 'client' is received as a parameter via $_POST from the user. In this scenario I think that what you want to do is prevent is SQL injection. If so you should solve it by using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to sanitize your input parameters:

```
// This could be supplied by a user, for example
$type = $POST['type'];

// Formulate Query
// This is the best way to perform an SQL query
// For more examples, see mysql_real_escape_string()
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM username 
    WHERE type='%s',
    mysql_real_escape_string($type));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);

...
```

I took this sample from the [mysql-query reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and adapted it for your needs.